# Perl parsing for SQL scripts

Tags: sql, regex, perl

I have many long sql files that include a bunch of discrete sql commands. Basically the files drop and then recreate a bunch of stored procedures with some modifications.

I need to parse them out to get the individual drop/create scrips.

Perl is my first choice since it is good at parsing...but I'm not very experienced with Perl...

Here is what I have so far (note I substantially re-wrote my original attempt):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $use = "";
my $use = "USE mydatabase;";

undef $/;               # Enable 'slurp' mode
open my $fh, '<', 'AlterSprocs.sql' or die;
$/= 'DROP PROCEDURE';
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
$n ++;
$row = $use  . "\n" . "GO"  . "\n" . 'DROP PROCEDURE' . $row . ';';
my $find = 'DROP PROCEDURE;';
my $replace = "";
$row =~ s/$find/$replace/g;

open (MYFILE, '>', $n);
print MYFILE $row;
close (MYFILE);
```

The text I am parsing looks something like:

```
Use mydatabase;
GO
Drop Procedure [blah1]
Create Procedure [blah1]
[Sql stuff]

Drop Procedure [blah2]
Create Procedure [blah2]
[Sql stuff]

[repeat blah3....blah4...etc...etc..]
```

This gives me files named 1, 2, 3, etc with the discrete stored procedures in them. I had to do some weird additions and replaces with the text to get it right...but it works. The last file will end up with an extra ";" but...that should be safe.

The main problem I have now is that the first file is empty because of the way I am parsing on "Drop Procedure". I tried to handle this by putting in an if/else in the while loop that wouldn't do anything if n=0 besides setting n++;

```
if ($n = 0)
{$n++;}
else {all the other stuff I actually want to do}
```

, but this only created one file (named 1).

I still need to pull out the name of the stored procedure so I can use that to name the output files instead of $n, but I think that will be somewhat straight forward since it is the first line.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to get the output you show from the script included in your post.

Comment: Perl is only good at parsing if you know Perl! Otherwise, you'll probably be more productive in a language that you know better.

Comment: I don't even see any attempt at iterating over multiple matches.

Comment: So which language to choose that does not require loops to loop over stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a fairly different solution from where I started:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $file_name = "";
my $first_line = "";

undef $/;               # Enable 'slurp' mode

open my $fh, '<', 'AlterSprocs.sql' or die;


$/= 'DROP PROCEDURE';
while (my $row = <$fh>) {

{
$n ++;
if ( $row =~ /\[dbo].\[(.*?)\]/ )
{
$file_name = $1;
$row = 'DROP PROCEDURE' . $row . ';';
my $find = 'DROP PROCEDURE;';
my $replace = "";
$row =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
$first_line = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects with(nolock) WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N\'[dbo].[' . $file_name . ']\'))' . "\n";
open (MYFILE, '>', "dbo." . $file_name . ".prc");
print MYFILE $first_line;
print MYFILE $row;
close (MYFILE); 
}
}

close $fh or die "Could not close sample.txt: $!";
```

This massages the individual files it creates into a format that our automated sproc executor likes and names the files after the sprocs in question.

Comment: `$row = 'DROP PROCEDURE' . $row . ';' # Be sure to put DROP PROCEDURE IN
$row =~ s/DROP PROCEDURE//g; # We wouldn't want the regex to go hungry`